# How to get catch error 404 error in Axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I have this snippet of code (part of a function), notice the "**BadURL**" at the end of the URL:

import axios from "axios";

```
try {
  return axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/featureFlagBadURL", {
    flagName: "newJqueryAjaxListener",
    defaultValue: "false",
  });
} catch (error) {
  return { data: 'false' }
}
```

But canno't get into the `catch` block, says:

```
(node:7676) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Request failed with status code 404
```

I can catch the error only if i wrap the function call itself outside the class

Comment: Axios returns a promise, so you can use `.catch()` to handle your error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Axios.post(...)` is an asynchronous call that returns a promise, that statement doesn't fail, and even if it does, it's not because of the HTTP request failing.

What you need to use is the `.then()` and `.catch()` methods of the returned promise to handle the request.

```
return axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/featureFlagBadURL", {
    flagName: "newJqueryAjaxListener",
    defaultValue: "false"
}).then((results) => {
    console.log('yay', results);
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log('oops', error);
});
```

Another alternative is to use `async` `await`.

```
async function handler() {
    try {
        const results = await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/featureFlagBadURL", {
            flagName: "newJqueryAjaxListener",
            defaultValue: "false",
        });
        console.log('yay', results);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log('oops', error);
        return { data: 'false' };
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
  return axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/featureFlagBadURL", {
    flagName: "newJqueryAjaxListener",
    defaultValue: "false",
  }).then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  }).then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

[source](https://axios-http.com/docs/example)

Comment: Want to async await my code, not then catch

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the error and check the status code. then you can handle it. Maybe witch switch case or simple if. i do it for 404 . see the cod below:

```
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/api/featureFlagBadURL", {
    flagName: "newJqueryAjaxListener",
    defaultValue: "false",
  }).then((res) => {
    // handle response => res.data
    console.log(response);
  }).catch((error) => {
    if (error.response) {
      if(error.response.status === 404) {
        console.log('BAD URL')
        // or 
        console.log(error.response.statusText) // "Not Found" 
      }
    }
  }
```